# Change the default file extension icon on vscode-icons don´t works

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to change the icon from the extension **test.js**. I found this documentation [vscode-icons Fine tuning](https://github.com/vscode-icons/vscode-icons/wiki/FineTuning) on my settings file `settings.json` I put:

```
{
  "vsicons.associations.files": [
    { "icon": "test", "extensions": ["test.js"], "format": "svg", "overrides": "test.js" }
  ]
}
```

But don't work, and when I change it to js, works:

```
{
  "vsicons.associations.files": [
    { "icon": "test", "extensions": ["js"], "format": "svg", "overrides": "js" }
  ]
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id` of the icon is `testjs`. 
[Answare by JimiC](https://github.com/vscode-icons/vscode-icons/issues/2358#issuecomment-580774277)

```
{
  "vsicons.associations.files": [
    { "icon": "test", "format": "svg", "overrides": "testjs" }
  ]
```